# Dyanamic Oracle Error

Tags: oracle, plsql

getting an error "ORA-00905 missing keyword" from the inner exception Begin and end;Any idea ?
passing all the table name based on the deptno (dyanmically) 
Inner begin is throwing that error.
getting an error "ORA-00905 missing keyword" from the inner exception Begin and end;Any idea ?
passing all the table name based on the deptno (dyanmically) 
Inner begin is throwing that error.

```
enter code here


declare
  type deptcursor is ref cursor;
  c1 deptcursor;
  v_records abc%rowtype;
begin
  if deptno=10
    v_table=abc;
    v_table1=abc1;
  elsif deptno=20
    v_table=xyz;
    v_table1=xyz1;
  end if;

  v_cursor= 'select * from '||v_table||'';

  begin
    -- issue loop
    OPEN C1 FOR v_cursor;

    LOOP
      FETCH C1
        INTO v_records.column1,v_records.column2,v_records.column3;

      EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND; 

      BEGIN -- begin start
        v_select:='select sum(NVL(salary,0)) ,sum(NVL(salary1,0))
                     INTO v_sal ,v_sal1
                     from '||v_table1||' 
                     where col1 ='''||v_records.column1||'''
                       and col2 ='''||v_records.column2||'''
                       and col3 IN (select col3
                                      from XXYYZZ
                                      where column1 = '''||newvariable passing from procedure||'''
                                        and column2 = '''||v_records.column2||''')';
        --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_select);
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_select; 
      exception
        when others then
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sqlerrm);
      end; -- end
    end loop;
  end;
```

Comment: What is `newvariable passing from procedure`?

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you have `if deptno=10` without a following `then`. Another is that the `elsif` in the same `if` statement also lacks a `then`. In PL/SQL an `if` statement should generally be:

```
IF condition THEN
  block_of_code;
ELSIF condition2 THEN
  another_block_of_code;
ELSE
  yet_another_block_of_code;
END IF;
```

[Documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS391)

In addition `v_cursor= 'select * from '||v_table||'';` should be

```
v_cursor := 'select * from '||v_table||'';
```

This is because the assignment operator in PL/SQL is `:=`, not `=` as it is in C, C++, Java, C#, etc.

Finally, it appears you're missing one END statement at the end of your code.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I think, in your code:

```
 if deptno=10
    v_table=abc;
    v_table1=abc1;
  elsif deptno=20
    v_table=xyz;
    v_table1=xyz1;
  end if;
```

The assignments should be ":=" instead of just "=". ALso, assuming "abc", "abc1" etc are literals and not variables, try enclosing in single-quotes:

```
 if deptno=10
    v_table:='abc';
    v_table1:='abc1';
  elsif deptno=20
    v_table:='xyz';
    v_table1:='xyz1';
  end if;
```